# Java - Getting rid of a compiler warning?

Tags: java, eclipse, casting, warnings, hashmap

i have the following line of code which displays the following warning:

```
HashMap<String,String> currentItem = (HashMap<String,String>) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
// Warning: Type Safety: Unckecked cast from Object to HashMap <String,String>
```

How can i get rid of this warning?

Comment: I notice you included the "eclipse" tag. Is the warning coming from the IDE or the compiler, or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the getItemAtPosition method return a generic HashMap, so you don't have to cast it.  Either that or use the appropriate annotation -- @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Comment: Rather go for fixing the method to return a generic HashMap. 
In some cases you are cannot change the code for example if you are using someone elses code and you cannot edit it. Then go for SuppressWarnings.

We sometimes need to do JUnit testing on code that we cannot edit and to avoid warnings all over the place and rather focus on actual warnings we add the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") for those cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress it with the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation on the line before the declaration:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashMap<String,String> currentItem = (HashMap<String,String>) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
// Warning: Type Safety: Unckecked cast from Object to HashMap <String,String>
```

If you do this though, you should add a comment indicating why it's type-safe to cast it to a map of strings to strings.

Alternatively, if you're reading from the map only, you can cast it to `HashMap<?, ?>` and check the type of the objects you get out of the map with `instanceof`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SuppressWarnings` annotation.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html

But I would discourage you to do that, if you have access to the `adapter` and can refactor it, take advantage of Java generics and return the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this warning in your compiler preferences, see picture..

[image]

Comment: I think it is better not to switch this off by default. As this will ensure that the developer thought about each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If the getter is returning an `Object` because its generic, then you should verify that it does contain string values.

You can use a checked map to enforce the contract though:

```
Map<String, String> currentItem = Collections.checkedMap(
     adapter.itemAtPosition(position), String.class, String.class);
```

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedMap%28java.util.Map,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class%29